# Вывод бинарного дерева уровень за уровнем C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, бинарное-дерево, вывод

Есть простое бинарное дерево

```
struct Node
{
int x; 
Node *l, *r;
};
```

Необходимо вывести на экран все его элементы уровень за уровнем. Вопрос заключается в том, как это реализовать? Желательно в виде кода с подробными комментариями. К сожалению гугл мне не помог. Буду очень благодарен тому кто доходчиво объяснит.

Теперь есть функция BFS, но остается вопросом как вывести каждый уровень с новой строки?

```
void LOPrint(Node *root) {
if (root == NULL)
{
    return;
}
queue<Node *> q; 
q.push(root); 
while (!q.empty()) 
{
    Node* temp = q.front(); 
    q.pop();  
    cout << temp->x << " "; 

    if (temp->l != NULL)
        q.push(temp->l);  

    if (temp->r != NULL)
        q.push(temp->r);  
}
cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: прочитайте про `BFS` что-нибудь. В гугле есть.

Comment: Пример кода есть в книге по алгоритмам автор  седжвик